# WPF or C# convert Html to Doc

Tags: c#, .net, html, wpf, doc

How can I convert HTML with images to Word Document(Doc not Docx) in WPF? Please tell me a free lib or other solution, but preferably with no office installed on OS.

Comment: There is no way to do this meeting your requirements - HTML->Doc binary, WPF, free. It's that simple. If you stick with these requirements, you won't find anything. If you change your requirements, more options are available.

Comment: WPF not critical requirement, it may be simple c#. Or in worst way c++.

Comment: with minimum requirements: i want free HTML to Doc on c#(or on c++ in bad way, or in worst way on Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can go with rtf instead of doc, you can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

You must use older version 4.*, since version 5 only pdf is supported.

Comment: Thanks! this lib is opensource and respond to all my requirements.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://www.sautinsoft.com/downloads.php).

Answer (score 1):

If RTF is a valid output option for you (Microsoft Word opens .RTF file without any specific configuration, they're just bigger in size, in general), there is an interesting free project here: [XHTML2RTF: An HTML to RTF conversion tool based on XSL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/XHTML2RTF.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coolutils.com/totalhtmlconverterx

Comment: The question has nothing to do with PDF.

Comment: Also not free. and in contrast with privious huge and more complicated in use.